# findViewById returns null in a custom view with subviews inside

Tags: android, null, android-custom-view, findviewbyid

I'm developing a View that shows a stack of messages making fadeIn,fadeOut and wait time between them. It has a stack of messages and when I need to display some of them I added to it. This view hasn't a specific design so the user can customize like he wants.

I have written well the 3 super constructors.

The XML layout is the next:

```
    [... Others views ...]

    <com.example.lectorrss.Views.StatusMessage
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/statusMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#6894ed">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Hola"
                android:textColor="#fff"></TextView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </com.example.lectorrss.Views.StatusMessage>


[... Other views ...]
```

In this case, I want my custom view shows the views that are inside (progress bar + textview) and then apply the behaviour I want.

The code of my CustomView is:

```
public class StatusMessage extends ViewGroup{

    private List<String> messagesStack;
    private Worker worker;

    public StatusMessage(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public StatusMessage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public StatusMessage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
     }


    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {

        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        TextView txtView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.message);
        if(txtView == null){
            Log.d("BrowsePortal", "TextView null");
        }else{
            // HERE, THE CODE CAN FIND OK THE VIEW I WANT
            Log.d("BrowsePortal", "TextView not null");
        }

        worker = new Worker(this);
        worker.execute();

    }

    [Other logic code about view]

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    }

}
```

But as my view needs time of wait between messages, and uses animation, I need to create an AsyncTask:

```
public class Worker extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void>{

    private StatusMessage view;

    public Worker(StatusMessage view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        [I supressed all logic code here]
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
        if(txtView == null){
            // But here the code return null
            Log.d("BrowsePortal", "TextView null");
        }else{
            Log.d("BrowsePortal", "TextView not null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        [I supressed all logic code here]
    }
}
```

My problem is that from asynctask, on the progressUpdate, when I need to access to the textview, findviewbyid returns null. But trying to access the same view from custom view class instead asynctask, it works. Why from view class I can access to textview but from asynctask not?

Also, in post execute, the same code returns me null.

My asynctask receives well in her constructor the view so from here would work well as from customview.

Comment: What kind of code is obscured with "[Other logic code about view]"? Do you remove the view at any point in your Apps life cycle?

Comment: @Knossos `[Other logic code about view]` is code related with `StatusMessage.stackMessages` property. Are methods like `addMessageToStack()`, `getNextMessageFromStack()`, `areThereMessages()`... Not important, I though, for that I supressed it. Also they don't operate with the view. On the other hand, in `Worker` class, the code hidden is related with animations, wait time etc... I supposed that animation code could be doing something wrong but a few minutes ago, a remove all leaving the AsyncTask only with the `if` check of TextView but it still working bad.

Comment: I am baffled I must say. If in onAttachedToWindow() you get "TextView not null" and in the AsyncTask you get "TextView null". Could you try two tests? 1. Create a member variable TextView and instantiate it using the View in the Constructor itself. Remove the instancing code from onProgressUpdate. Works? 2. Pass the TextView itself into the AsyncTask, set it to a member variable, and test its integrity in onProgressUpdate().

Comment: @Knossos Sorry for taking to answer but I took a break. Well, in the first case you said me, in the constructor, it can't find the TextView. It returns null. But if I pass as parameter the textview pre-finded in the other class, it works well. Returns not null. But why? Should be work in the other way :( I'm not sure if the problem is the AsyncTask but I access to the UI in the correct methods.

Comment: @Knossos Solved! Eclipse always trolls me importing `android.R` instead of `package.R`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with this line:

`import android.R` which I change to `import [app_package].R;`.

Then, when I put this line:

`TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);`

... the method could not find the textview because was using as ID, a resource from `android.R` instead of `package.R`.

**The most strange is that along activities I made this time ago, sometimes I did the same mistake, but I could fix quickly because Eclipse said me that the resource specified wasnt found underlining the resource line, but for some reason, in this case didn't notify me. Maybe `R.id.message` is reserved for android.R.**

Comment: Make sure that you accept your own answer as soon as you can. So that others know what the problem was.